# ranges of ranges to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, range-v3

Suppose I have a range of T's called rng. I can do

```
auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, bin_op);
```

groups now being a range of ranges of T's.

I can also do this

```
auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, bin_op) | ranges::to_vector;
```

to get a vector of ranges of T's. However this

```
auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, bin_op)
            | ranges::to_vector
            | ranges::action::transform([] (auto r) { return r | ranges::to_vector; };
```

as well as

```
auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, bin_op)
            | ranges::to_vector
            | ranges::action::transform([] (auto r) { return std::vector<T>{} | ranges::action::push_back; };
```

won't work since apparently ranges::action::transform() returns void in this case and "The result type of the function passed to action::transform must be writable back into the source range".

So how do I turn my ranges of ranges into a vector of vectors?

Note: Sorry for the bad tags, but I couldn't find a ranges/ranges-ts/ranges-v3 tag, I am not allowed to create one and couldn't use it in the title.

Comment: `ranges::action::transform` != `ranges::view::transform`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Rangesv3, my reading of the docs gives me something like this:

```
auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, bin_op)
        | ranges::view::transform( ranges::to_vector )
        | ranges::to_vector;
```

or maybe

```
auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, bin_op)
        | ranges::view::transform( [] (auto r) { return r | ranges::to_vector; } )
        | ranges::to_vector;
```

(I recall that `ranges::to_vector` could be used in a function-style way, but I could be wrong, or things could have changed.  The first one assumes it can be; the second doesn't.)

What this does is it first transforms the lazy range of ranges into a lazy range of vectors.

It then transforms the lazy range of vectors into a vector of vectors.

This works better (inside-out) because the intermediate products are lazy "on the outside".  There may be a way to do it from the outside-in, but a vector of lazy ranges *has to actually exist* in a way that a lazy range of vectors does not.

Comment: Indeed this works. So the idea is to work from inside to outside as opposed to outside to inside. Any idea why the other direction won't work?

Comment: @rich maybe it could, but it would be inefficient because vectors exist while ranges are lazy.  You can have an intermediate lazy range of vectors for 0 cost, but an intermediate vector of lazy ranges must exist and has a cost.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Kinda embarrassing that my Haskell brain didn't notice... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `ranges::to` to convert the range of ranges into a vector of vectors. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/all.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/group_by.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> rng {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    auto groups = ranges::view::group_by(rng, [](int i, int j){
        return j/3 == i/3;
    });

    auto vs = groups | ranges::to<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;

    // Display the result: [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9]]
    std::cout << ranges::view::transform(vs, ranges::view::all) << std::endl;
}
```

---

June 10, 2020: Previously, this answer recommended simply assigning from `groups` to a `vector<vector<int>>` variable because range-v3 used to support implicit conversions from views to containers. The implicit conversions were problematic, and so they were dropped. `ranges::to` is now the idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Oh wow - that is way more easy than anticipated ;)  I really wish the docs would be more detailled - so many things I don't get... (expect a question about std::multimap in the near future)

Comment: I can no longer make "view to container" conversions using assignment. What is the idiomatic way, at this point, to create a new container object from a view? Say for a simpler example, just a `std::vector<int> vi{1, 2};` transformed into a `long int` view, `vi | views::transform(convert_to<long int>{})`, from which I would like to create a `std::vector<long int>` object.

Comment: The implicit conversions from views to containers have been removed because they were problematic. `ranges::to` is the right way to do this. I have updated the answer. Thanks.